# load raster in original resolution in ArcScene

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, 3d-analyst, arcscene

Each time I load a high resolution raster in ArcScene, it automatically starts to resample it and starts making pyramids, thus making the raster pixelated once the resampling finishes.

How can I undo the resampling in ArcScene?

**Update**

Even after deleting the pyramids or loading the raster in its original form without resampling; ArcScene still lowers the resolution of the raster. Whereas, this is not the case in ArcMap. But, I have to work in ArcScene.

**ArcScene**

[image]

**ArcMap**

[image]

Comment: On a side note, even when I reload the raster to get the resampling prompt and I select not to resample, it takes more time to load the raster as compared to the resampling process, but even then the raster is pixelated.

Comment: Also when I load the same file in ArcMap without resampling, the software loads the raster in its original resolution.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I think the blog post has the fix you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this old blog detailing your issue and the fix:
https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-desktop/3d-gis/adjusting-image-raster-display-quality-in-arcscene/

To delete pyramids and prevent arcmap from automatically building them follow these steps:

1. Delete pyramids
   https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/deleting-pyramids-from-a-raster-dataset.htm
2. Set ArcGIS to Never Build pyramids automatically
   https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/changing-the-default-setting-for-building-pyramids.htm